# Multi-field search for synonym in the query string

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

It looks like Elasticsearch does not take field analyzers into account for multi-field search using query string, without specifying field.
Can this be configured for index or specified in the query?

Here it is a hands on example.

Given files from [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/commit/a3828c6161daa9fe31eacdcc93a286119ac470fd) ([spring-data-elasticsearch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch)).
There is a test `SynonymRepositoryTests`, which will pass with `QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("text:british")` and `QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("british").analyzer("synonym_analyzer")` queries.

Is it possible to make it passing with `QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("british")` query, without specifying field and analyzer for query?

Comment: do you want `synonym_analyzer` applied to all fields?

Comment: no, I have different analyzers for different fields and want make them searchable by simple query string

Answer (score 1):

You could query without specifying fields or analyzers. By default `query string query` will query on [_all](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) field which is combination of all fields and uses [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). so `QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("british")` will work.

You can [exclude](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#excluding-from-all) some fields from all fields while creating index and you can also create custom all field with the help of [copy_to](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#custom-all-fields) functionality.

**UPDATE**

You would have to use your **custom analyzer** on `_all` fields while creating index.

```
PUT text_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "edge_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "prefix_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "trim",
            "edge_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "analyzer": "prefix_analyzer"  <---- your synonym analyzer
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "tag": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "simple"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can replace *prefix_analyzer* with your *synonym_analyzer* and then it should work.

Comment: It does not work, since `british` is a synonym for `english`, which is defined in the field analyzer

Comment: I see the problem, I have updated my answer, let me know if it does not work.

Comment: thanks for trying to help, but this configuration means, that synonym analyzer will be applied to all fields, but I want to have analyzers work as they particularly configured per each field, and be able to search for all of them within one query

Comment: **not** all fields, only **_all** field, you would still be able to query other fields according to their own analyzers

Comment: as you said, *_all* field is a combination of all fields, so that, now, synonym analyzer will be applied to all its content, is it correct?